# How to detect when a user presses a key outside of the app

Tags: java, swing

So I tried to look a bit in forums and StackOverflow but nothing worked for me I need when enter is pressed to stop my code this is my code `

JFrame f;

```
    JTextField I;

    // JButton
    JToggleButton b;
 
    // label to display text
    JLabel l;

    f = new JFrame("AutoClicker");

    i = new JTextField("100");

    // create a label to display text
    l = new JLabel("clicks/seconds");

    // create a new buttons
    b = new JToggleButton("Start");

    // create a panel to add buttons
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    // add buttons and textfield to panel
    p.add(b);
    p.add(i);
    p.add(l);


    // setbackground of panel
    p.setBackground(Color.red);

    // add panel to frame
    f.add(p);

    // set the size of frame
    f.setSize(280, 80);

    f.setVisible(true);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int jml = Integer.parseInt(i.getText());
            if(jml < 50)
            {
                jml = 50;
            }
            AutoClicker(jml);
        }
    });
}

static void AutoClicker(int jml)
{
    while(true)
    {
        try{
            Robot r = new Robot();
            int button = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;
            r.mousePress(button);
            Thread.sleep(jml);
            r.mouseRelease(button);
            Thread.sleep(jml);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("not good");
        }
    }

}
```

}`

I tried to add a KeyListener but it did not work.
I don't understand why it doesn't work so if you can just help me know why it doesn't work it would be much apreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`KeyListener` isn't going to solve the problem of the fact that you are simply not handling the potential of `Integer.parseInt` to throw an exception - I mean, how can it convert `""` or `"This is not a number"` to an `int`.  In those cases it throws an exception

The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) clearly state

> **Throws:**
> `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a
> parsable integer.

Go back and have a look at the original error you were getting from your previous question on this exact topic

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter"`

It's telling you exactly what the problem is - the text `"Enter"` can not be converted to an `int` value.

YOU have to handle this possibility.  No offence, but this is honestly basic Java 101.  See [Catching and Handling Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)

Another option which "might" help is to use a [formatted text field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

You also don't seem to have a firm grip on the concept of what a "event driven environment" is or what the potential risk of what doing something like `while (true)` will do if executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. This makes me think you've got yourself in over all head.

You're going to want to learn about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) as `AutoClicker` should never be called within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, which is going to lead you another area of complexity, concurrency and all the joys that brings.

## Updated

Wow, you changed the title.  Maybe a better description of the problem you're trying to solve would have a gotten a better answer.  In short, you can't, not natively in Java anyway.  The only way you can detect keyboard input out side of the app is using native integration, JNA/JNI.  Plenty of examples about, for [example](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+jni+keyboard+hook&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)